# Cypress.io: How to use Fixtures?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, fixtures

I actually use the following code:

```
const userType = new Map([['Manager', '1'],['Developer', '2' ]]) 
for (const [key, value] of usertypes.entries()) 
{
    it('log in', () => 
    {
        cy.login(key,value)
        
        cy.xpath('path')
        .click()
         cy.xpath('path')                        
        .should('have.value' , key)         
    })
}
```

To use the Users in other tests I want to define usertypes in a fixture named users. How can I use this fixture with this test?
My Json File looks like :

```
[[
     {"key": "Manager"},
     {"value": "1"}
],

[
    {"key": "Developer"},
    {"value": "2" }
]]
```

I tried to use cy.fixture in the beforeElse but I dont need this in every test and it was not right.
How can I use the data of users.json in my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your test, the test data is defined outside the `it()`, so `cy.fixture()` will not be possible to call outside a running test. In this case I will recommend you to use import, so:

1. Create a `.js` file(let's say in the `fixtures` folder) with your users
   (don't forget `Map` allows keys of any type, so no object notation needed):

```
export const users =  [
    [
        "Manager", 1
    ],

    [
        "Developer", 2
    ]
]
```

2. Import the variable and pass it as argument to your map constructor:

```
import { users } from '../fixtures/your_file.js';
```

```
const userCred = new Map(users);
   for (const [name, password] of userCred.entries()) {
       it('log in', () => {
           cy.login(name, password)
       })
   }
```

Comment: the .js file must be in the integration folder. otherwise everything works great. Thank you for your help :)